# Nested form only shows only text fields for one attribute but should be three?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm having a problem with my nested form.

Models:

```
class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_questions
  belongs_to :question

  validates :user_question_group, presence: true
  validates :question, presence: true
  validates :answer, presence: true
end
```

and the other one:

```
class UserQuestionGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :user_answers, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:answer].blank? }

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

So I create the question in the controller:

```
  def new
    @user_question_group = UserQuestionGroup.new(user_id: current_user.id)

    QuestionGroup.all.each do |ag|
      ag.questions.each do |a|
        @user_question_group.user_questions.build(questions_id: a.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

Which works which I can see when I simply inspect: @user_question_group.user_questions. I can see all questions.

But when I actually want to show the form it only show one form for the question and it's even empty even though question_id should have a number.

```
...
<%= form_for(@user_question_group, :url => user_user_question_groups_path(@current_user)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>

  <%#= @user_question_group.user_questions.inspect %>
  <%= fields_for :user_questions do |fa| %> 
    <p>
      <%= fa.label :question_id %>
      <%= fa.text_field :question_id %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= fa.label :answer %>
      <%= fa.text_field :answer %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
...
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `fields_for` as a method of the form, this way:

```
...
<%= form_for(@user_question_group, :url => user_user_question_groups_path(@current_user)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>

  <%#= @user_question_group.user_questions.inspect %>
  <%= f.fields_for :user_questions do |fa| %> 
    <p>
      <%= fa.label :question_id %>
      <%= fa.text_field :question_id %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= fa.label :answer %>
      <%= fa.text_field :answer %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
...
```

Comment: Of course! Stared at it for ages and didn't see it. Thanks a lot for pointing my typo out! :)